# What is the appropriate place to include Action Listner Block

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener

Okay, so I have three classes. 
1.) Program Driver-main class 2.)TopPanel 3.) Frame
My Action Listener to logout button is working okay but I just kind of thought maybe there's a better way to separate blocks for Action Listeners. Please bear with me as I'm new with this.
What is the best way to separate Action Listeners block? Do I need to implement Action Listener on class everytime or can I do the same thing I did here

Here's my code.
TopPanel class

```
public class TopPanel extends JPanel{
//DECLARATION

JButton logOutButton = new JButton("Logout");
TopTabbedPane topTabbedPane = new TopTabbedPane();
private final Border myLineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);

//CONSTRUCTOR    
public TopPanel(){
    setPanelInitialProperties();
    addComponents();

}

//METHODS
private void setPanelInitialProperties(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setBorder(myLineBorder); //sets a Line Border for this panel
    //setBackground(Color.red);
}

private void addComponents(){
    GridBagConstraints topTabbedPaneGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints logOutButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();

    topTabbedPaneGBC.gridx = 0;
    topTabbedPaneGBC.gridy = 1;
    topTabbedPaneGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    this.add(topTabbedPane,topTabbedPaneGBC); //adds TabbedPane holding Home, Administration... to this Top Panel

     logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int logOutChoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to logout?");
            if(logOutChoice == 0){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

    logOutButtonGBC.gridx = 0;
    logOutButtonGBC.gridy = 0;
    logOutButtonGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    this.add(logOutButton,logOutButtonGBC);
}


}
```

And here's for the frame class

```
public class TopFrame extends JFrame {
//DECLARATION
TopPanel topPanel = new TopPanel(); //create an object 

//CONSTRUCTOR 1:
public TopFrame(){
    setFrameInitialProperties();
    addComponentsToPane();
}

//METHOD 1: 
private void setFrameInitialProperties(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300,700)); //set it's dimensions or it's size
    this.setVisible(true); //sets it's initial visibility to true so it shows on the screen when objects are created from this class
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Enrollment System");

    //always put pack() first before setLocationRelativeTo(null)
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
//METHOD 2:
private void addComponentsToPane(){
    Container myContainer = this.getContentPane(); //stores the Frame to a Container we named myContainer
        myContainer.add(topPanel); //adds one panel which we named topPanel
}
}
```

I'd appreciate any explanation or examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lot comes down to context.

With the inclusion of inner and anonymous classes, making `ActionListener`s has become WAY more easier, lambda expression can also reduce a lot of the clutter (but IMHO can make it harder to read and ascertain the API contracts).

In your case, when the contents of the `ActionListener` are only a few lines long, so an anonymous class, as you have, is more than suitable, it's isolate and contextual (now imagine you had to dig out a separate class just to see those few lines :P)

Larger more complex actions might require a inner class, to make the code easier to read, it remains contextual (as non-static inner classes can access  methods and fields of the outer class), but doesn't clutter the code.

The only time I might consider using an external class is if the functionality of the `ActionListener` is re-usable in some way, but then, I'd use the [Actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which are self contained units of work. The problem here, is you need to provide context to them, by passing a reference of the object which contains the methods/fields you need to work with, at this point, you need to make careful decisions about your design and this is where `interfaces` can really help

So, based on your current functionality, you could create a "generic" "logout" action, for example...

```
public class LogoutAction extends AbstractAction {

    private LogoutAction parent;

    public CloseAction(String name, Component parent) {
        super(name);
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int logOutChoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, "Do you want to logout?");
        if (logOutChoice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(parent).dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

And then you could use it something like...

```
public class TopPanel extends JPanel{

    private JButton logOutButton;

    //...
    private void addComponents() {
        //...
        logOutButton = new JButton(new LogoutAction(this, "Logout"));
        //...
```

And that would be it, when the button is clicked, it will popup the question and if the user chooses <kbd>Ok</kbd>, the associated window will be closed (and if it's the last window it's configured to close on exit, the JVM will exit)